# Jquery slideshow won't fade with my pictures first time around, but will with random pics off the internet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I have this jquery slideshow that fades images ever 3 seconds, when using the images in the second slideshow, just off a random google search, all the images fade. If I use relative links or even links off of my website, they won't fade until the second time around. In the code below, the second image in the first slideshow from newtimere.com is my image. 
When the slideshow comes to this image neither slideshow will fade until the second time around, but all other images fade the first time around. I have no idea what's going on. I've tried jquery 2.2.4 and 3.2.1

```js
    $('.jquerySlideshow').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var bgimg = $this.data("bgimg");
      var bgimgcss = "url(" + bgimg + ")"
      $this.css( "background-image", bgimgcss );
    });
    
    $('.jquerySlideshow-out').each(function() {
        // scope everything for each slideshow
        var $this = this;
        $('> :gt(0)', $this).hide();
        setInterval(function() {
            $('> :first-child', $this).fadeOut()
                .next().fadeIn()
                .end().appendTo($this);
        }, 3000);
    });
```

```css
    .jquerySlideshow-out {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .jquerySlideshow {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 0;
      background: no-repeat center center fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative; height: 500px; width: 100%;">
        <div class="jquerySlideshow-out">
            <div class="jquerySlideshow" data-bgimg="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/K3UdS0t311DpKIiq614Ix6cRanFYxueEFaLF3T0bPQLGcJtqzw5ps3ClI85nK7jB4ElbKBs8xg=s640-h400-e365"></div>
            <div class="jquerySlideshow" data-bgimg="http://www.newtimere.com/img/portfolio/portfolio4.jpg"></div>
            <div class="jquerySlideshow" data-bgimg="http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/magellanic-clouds.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="position: relative; height: 500px; width: 100%;">
        <div class="jquerySlideshow-out">
            <div class="jquerySlideshow" data-bgimg="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/K3UdS0t311DpKIiq614Ix6cRanFYxueEFaLF3T0bPQLGcJtqzw5ps3ClI85nK7jB4ElbKBs8xg=s640-h400-e365"></div>
            <div class="jquerySlideshow" data-bgimg="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lt0WQ8JzLz4/maxresdefault.jpg"></div>
            <div class="jquerySlideshow" data-bgimg="http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/magellanic-clouds.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working as you expect it to. Check out the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ytgs8j8b/

Comment: After testing it in firefox I realized this is an issue with chrome, or at least my chrome. Thanks for the help though! Just glad I got it figured out :)